# Extending MUI v5 Chip colors gives undefined (reading 'contrastText') error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to extend MUI v5 Chip colors but get an error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contrastText')

As far I understand I need to add a `contrastText` prop to palette but it's not clear where or how to add it. I tried to add it to `palette.ts` as props but no success, I tried to add it to palette.ts `primary` prop but also without success.

**palette.ts** looks like this:

```
export const palette = {
  primary: {
    25: '#FCFAFF',
    // some other colors
  },

  warning: {
    // some colors
  },
  success: {
    // some colors
  },
};
```

**theme.ts**

```
 const themeOptions = {
     palette
   };
   

   let theme = createTheme(themeOptions);
   theme = createTheme(theme, { // some component styling });
  

  declare module '@mui/material/Chip' {
    interface ChipPropsColorOverrides {
      'not-ready': true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it in your palette color sth like this :

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main:'#FCFAFF',
      contrastText:'#FCFAFF'
     }
  },
});
```

the point is when you add color you need to add as main or other keys value

here is it's interface :

```
interface PaletteColor {
  light?: string;
  main: string;
  dark?: string;
  contrastText?: string;
}
```

and if you want to add new color you need to obey this structure

forexample :

```
   const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main:'#FCFAFF',
      contrastText:'#FCFAFF'
    },
    lightGray:{
      main:'#a1a1a1',
    }
  },
});
```

and in ChipPropsColorOverrides :

```
  declare module '@mui/material/Chip' {
    interface ChipPropsColorOverrides {
      'lightGray': true
    }
  }
```

so,

> primary: {
> 25: '#FCFAFF' },

is wrong and you need to use one of PaletteColor  keys